# Converting xml into a table with sorted elements

Tags: html, xml, sorting, xslt, html-table

I have the following xml file

```
?xml version="1.0"?>
    <Schedule> 
            <Lesson>
                    <Title>Maths</Title>
                    <Lecture Classroom="100">
                        <Day>Tuesday</Day>
                        <Time>12:00</Time>
                    </Lecture>
                    <Lecture Classroom="101">
                        <Day>Thursday</Day>
                        <Time>11:00</Time>
                    </Lecture>
            </Lesson>
            <Lesson>
                    <Title>Scientific Computing</Title>
                    <Lecture Classroom="103">
                        <Day>Monday</Day>
                        <Time>09:00</Time>
                    </Lecture>
            </Lesson>
}
```

I want to simply make the elements be in a table form but i want them to be sorted by day and coloured in groups(e.g. the lessons that take place on Day="Monday" to be on the first rows of the table and colored differently than the other days' lessons)
I have made this already:

```
     <table border="1">
 <tr bgcolor="#888888 ">
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Professor</th>
    <th>Day</th>
 </tr>
 <xsl:for-each select="Schedule/Lesson">
 <tr bgcolor="#F00000 ">
 <td><xsl:value-of select="Title"/> </td>
 <td><xsl:value-of select="Professor"/> </td>
 <td><xsl:value-of select="Lecture/Day"/> </td>
 </tr>
 </xsl:for-each>
 </table>
```

Any ideas of how can i make them sorted and coloured properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <Schedule> 
            <Lesson>
                    <Title>Maths</Title>
                    <Lecture Classroom="100">
                        <Day>Tuesday</Day>
                        <Time>12:00</Time>
                    </Lecture>
                    <Lecture Classroom="101">
                        <Day>Thursday</Day>
                        <Time>11:00</Time>
                    </Lecture>
            </Lesson>
            <Lesson>
                    <Title>Scientific Computing</Title>
                    <Lecture Classroom="103">
                        <Day>Monday</Day>
                        <Time>09:00</Time>
                    </Lecture>
            </Lesson>
    </Schedule>
```

**XSL:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
   <xsl:template match="/">
      <html>
         <body>
            <table border="1">
               <tr bgcolor="#888888">
                  <th>Title</th>
                  <th>Professor</th>
                  <th>Day</th>
               </tr>
               <xsl:for-each select="Schedule/Lesson/Lecture">
                  <xsl:sort select="Day" />
                  <tr>
                     <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="../Title" />
                     </td>
                     <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="@Classroom" />
                     </td>
                     <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="Day = 'Monday'">
                           <td bgcolor="#F00000">
                              <xsl:value-of select="Day" />
                           </td>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                           <td>
                              <xsl:value-of select="Day" />
                           </td>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                     </xsl:choose>
                  </tr>
               </xsl:for-each>
            </table>
         </body>
      </html>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output:**

```
<html>
   <body>
      <table border="1">
         <tr bgcolor="#888888">
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Professor</th>
            <th>Day</th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Scientific Computing</td>
            <td>103</td>
            <td bgcolor="#F00000">Monday</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Maths</td>
            <td>101</td>
            <td>Thursday</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Maths</td>
            <td>100</td>
            <td>Tuesday</td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

Meaning '`Mondays`' will be in **RED** color in HTML.

Simply add more `when test` to give colors to the other days if you need.

```
<xsl:when test="Day = 'Tuesday'">
       <td bgcolor="#C66666">
            <xsl:value-of select="Day" />
       </td>
```

You might want to check these links out to learn more about sort and colors.

http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_sort.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_choose.asp

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that when you say "sorted" you mean in chronological order then I would recommend creating a template for the `Lecture` element in which you use the predicate of the `Day` element to have it put the items in order. You can then use a conditional for the attribute to color only the Monday classes.

Here is what the templates would look like

```
<xsl:template match="Schedule">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Title</td>
      <td>Professor</td>
      <td>Day</td>
    </tr>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Lesson/Lecture[Day='Monday']"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Lesson/Lecture[Day='Tuesday']"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Lesson/Lecture[Day='Wednesday']"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Lesson/Lecture[Day='Thursday']"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Lesson/Lecture[Day='Friday']"/>
  </table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Lecture">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <xsl:value-of select="../Title"/>
    </td>
    <td>
      <xsl:value-of select="@Classroom"/>
    </td>
    <td>
      <xsl:if test="Day = 'Monday'">
        <xsl:attribute name="style">background-color:red;</xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:value-of select="Day"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
</xsl:template>
```